# Check if substring exist in string from cmd/bat script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to check if `count` exists in `mycountry` or not, and then do some operations according.

My code snippet :

```
rem @ECHO OFF
cls
SET FILE="mycountry"
```

If true I want to run 3 statements and if false I want to run 3 other statements.

I have tried this combination:

```
Echo.%FILE% | findstr /C:"count">nul && (Echo.TRUE) || (Echo.FALSE)
```

But how to write multiple statements if the condition gets true? *I don't wanna use any flag variable.*

Below snippet is not working.

```
Echo.%FILE% | findstr /C:"count">nul && 
(
Echo.TRUE
echo "ran correct."
) 
|| (Echo.FALSE)
```

Comment: Do you want to check if a substring exists in a **variable** or in a **textfile**?

Comment: The snippet fails to work because the opening parenthesis of the code block has to be on the same line as the conditional execution  `&& (...` and also `) || (...` BTW here it doesn't matter, but don't inject a space in front of the pipe symbol `Echo.%FILE%| findstr`

Comment: Correct @LotPings, however the OP also states that they've 'tried this combination', `Echo.%FILE% | findstr /C:"count">nul && (Echo.TRUE) || (Echo.FALSE)`, which has parentheses on the correct line, and therefore does not exhibit the issue! My suspicion is that they've not provided accurate information in their question body.

Comment: I interpret `I have tried this combination` versus `Below snippet is not working` that the 1st **did** work, the latter not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [%errorlevel%](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html)  value combined with an if/else.
See the example below:

```
REM @echo off
cls
SET FILE="mycountry"
SET STR="TEST"

findstr %STR% %FILE% >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
    goto searchError
) else (
    goto searchSucces
)

:searchSucces
echo String %STR% found in file %FILE%
pause
exit

:searchError
echo String %STR% not found in file %FILE%
pause
exit
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code, *(integrated into a batch file)*, appears to work as expected:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "FILE="

Set /P "FILE=Enter String: "

If Not Defined FILE Exit /B

Echo.%FILE% | findstr /C:"count">nul && (Echo.TRUE) || (Echo.FALSE)

Pause
```

In addition, the following two methods both appear to work as expected:

Using `Echo` and `FindStr` *(as in your code)*:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "FILE="

Set /P "FILE=Enter String: "

Echo=%FILE%|FindStr /IC:"count">Nul 2>&1&&(Echo TRUE
    Echo Ran correct.
    Timeout 3 /NoBreak>Nul
    Echo Still running!)||Echo FALSE
Pause
```

Using variable substitution:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "FILE="

Set /P "FILE=Enter String: "

If /I "%FILE:count=%"=="%FILE%" (Echo FALSE) Else (Echo TRUE
    Echo Ran correct.
    Timeout 3 /NoBreak>Nul
    Echo Still running!)
Pause
```

If the examples above do not work for you, you should edit your question to include the actual code and strings you're using in your real world scenario. We cannot fix something we cannot see, especially if you don't fully explain the issue, *(`snippet is not working` is a statement only, not an explanation)*.